# Connecting to MS SQL Server via Eclipse

Tags: sql-server, eclipse

I have the Microsoft Studio and can connect to the server I wish to, so I know it works.  I am trying to set up the same thing from Eclipse.  I opened the "Database Development" perspective and did a "new SQL Server" connection.  It gave me a screen to select a driver, but the driver selection box was empty.

I found information on downloading a driver so I downloaded sqljdbc_6.0 and ran it.  They will not let us extract to C:Program Files so I extracted to c:MyProgramFiles.

It was a bit unclear what to do next.  I used Eclipse's help facility and it told me basically the same, but that when I make a new connection there should be a wizard to help, but there was no wizard.  There was also no "Manage Drivers" button which one help location said there should be.  So I am not sure how to add the driver I just downloaded.  Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have to click there as shown in the picture then choose the `JDBC` driver

and follow the other steps.

Comment: Thanks.  I did try that.  Someone else showed me DBeaver and I got that to work fine.  Is there a way using DBeaver you can use Java to query and get results?